# Iterate over dataframes, write a dictionary and append float values to keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have more than 6k dataframes that look like this,  gene_id remains constant in all the files but not copy_number:

```
gene_id             copy_number

ENSG00000223972.5   NaN
ENSG00000227232.5   NaN
ENSG00000278267.1   NaN
ENSG00000243485.3   NaN
ENSG00000274890.1   NaN
ENSG00000237613.2   NaN
ENSG00000268020.3   NaN
ENSG00000240361.1   1.0
ENSG00000186092.4   1.0
ENSG00000238009.5   1.0
```

My idea is to iterate through all the files, create a dictionary from the first file and when looping through the other files append the copy number corresponding to the gene_id:

```
{'ENSG00000223972.5': nan,
 'ENSG00000227232.5': nan,
 'ENSG00000278267.1': nan,
 'ENSG00000243485.3': nan,
 'ENSG00000274890.1': nan,
 'ENSG00000237613.2': nan,
 'ENSG00000268020.3': nan,
 'ENSG00000240361.1': 1.0,
 'ENSG00000186092.4': 1.0,
 'ENSG00000238009.5': 1.0}
```

Second file:

```
gene_id             copy_number

ENSG00000223972.5   3.0
ENSG00000227232.5   3.0
ENSG00000278267.1   3.0
ENSG00000243485.3   2.0
ENSG00000274890.1   2.0
ENSG00000237613.2   2.0
ENSG00000268020.3   2.0
ENSG00000240361.1   1.0
ENSG00000186092.4   1.0
ENSG00000238009.5   1.0
```

Final result idea:

```
    {'ENSG00000223972.5': nan, 3.0,
     'ENSG00000227232.5': nan, 3.0,
     'ENSG00000278267.1': nan, 3.0,
     'ENSG00000243485.3': nan, 2.0,
     'ENSG00000274890.1': nan, 2.0,
     'ENSG00000237613.2': nan, 2.0,
     'ENSG00000268020.3': nan, 2.0,
     'ENSG00000240361.1': 1.0, 1.0,
     'ENSG00000186092.4': 1.0, 1.0,
     'ENSG00000238009.5': 1.0, 1.0}
```

My code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/file1.tsv', sep = '\t')
dict1 = df1.to_dict()
   
#Iterate through all the files in folder:
 
genelevelpath = '/Users/user/myfiles/'
allfiles      = glob.glob(genelevelpath + '/*.tsv')
   for filename in allfiles:
      pd.read(file)
```

I need help to append floats from copy number to the dictionary and check that the key corresponds.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alicia. Any need to go from a `df` to a `dict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

genelevelpath = '/Users/user/myfiles/'

all_files = glob.glob(genelevelpath + '/*.tsv')

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in all_files))

df.groupby('gene_id')['copy_number'].apply(list)
```

Comment: This is exactly what  I want, but there are more. than 6k files taking a total of 6GB of space so I dont think pandas will be able to handle that. Isnt  it a more pythonic way to do it ?

Comment: If your system memory is sufficient to store all of the dataframes in memory, I don't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all values in the first dict should be lists (to_dict should automatically do this)

```
{'ENSG00000223972.5': [nan],
 'ENSG00000227232.5': [nan],
 'ENSG00000278267.1': [nan],
 'ENSG00000243485.3': [nan],
 'ENSG00000274890.1': [nan],
 'ENSG00000237613.2': [nan],
 'ENSG00000268020.3': [nan],
 'ENSG00000240361.1': [1.0],
 'ENSG00000186092.4': [1.0],
 'ENSG00000238009.5': [1.0]}
```

and then try like this:

```
for x,y in zip(list(firstDict.keys()),list(secondDict.keys())):
  firstDict[x].append(secondDict[y])
```